# Pass variables to the installer on OSX package Installer

Tags: macos, shell, variables, package, installation

I´m trying to pass variables to my post-installation script but seems like isn´t available. 
I tried this but doesn´t work:

```
sudo MY_VAR=VALUE installer -pkg my_package.pkg -target /
```

I need to access environments variables, without a config file, in post-installation script.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `export MY_VAR=VALUE` before command?

Comment: yes, I tried and didn't work either.

Comment: `shell` passes the environment variables to the `shell` scripts... are you sure you're using a `shell` script? isn't that a binary file? What is the output of `file installer` ?

Comment: Sorry, its a binary file called "installer". When it installs the pkg file, this one runs a script (post-install script). This last script its the one who I need to access to vars.

Comment: Maybe sudo breaks variable definition. Try `sudo su; export MY_VAR=VALUE; installer -pkg my_package.pkg -target / `

Comment: Tried too... and didn`t work...

Comment: I run out of ideas. Check the program documentation (if it's external) to understand how to pass that variable, maybe as a program parameter. I've never passed a variable to a binary like that, but usually, if it expects it, there is a way to give it to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `export var_name=value` won't work in this case. To achieve this you must use `launchctl` and export your variables by running `launchctl setenv var_name value`. After that, you can get the value of your variables using `launchctl getenv var_name`. Here you can see an example:

```
sh-3.2# launchctl setenv var1 hello      
sh-3.2# launchctl setenv var2 world
sh-3.2# launchctl getenv var1
hello
sh-3.2# launchctl getenv var2
world
```

You can also set multiple variables at once:

```
sh-3.2# launchctl setenv var3 one var4 line
sh-3.2# launchctl getenv var3
one
sh-3.2# launchctl getenv var4
line
```

To use this with your package, you can run something like this:

```
sh-3.2# launchctl setenv var_name value && installer -pkg your_package.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Bad news; it's blocked by SIP since Ventura 13.4

Comment: Is there another solution to this since SIP blocks this flow?